# How to enable background processing on web server

Tags: 20.04, apache2, php

I am running a web server with Ubuntu 20.04. I am trying to get a WordPress/Woocommerce plugin to work between WooCommerce and Square, but keep having sync issues. Support has stated we need to ensure background processing is enabled on my host (which is me). I have never had to enable this before and would *assume* this is enabled by default, but maybe not.

1. How can I confirm if this is enabled?
2. If not enabled how can I enable this processing?

This is the note from the support documentation:

**Does your site support background processing?** Background processing is required to successfully sync product data between Square and WooCommerce. Square and many other WooCommerce features/plugins require background processing. If your site fails, please contact your host to enable background processing/loopback connections. While some hosts may identify this as a security issue, there’s no security threat to using a loopback connection and, if done correctly, it won’t increase server usage. Quality hosts will mitigate increased server usage with rate limiting.

Comment: "Background processing" as they describe it is too vague and doesn't sound like something one would enable or disable on Ubuntu itself. Can you ask the support people to provide some documentation or links to what they mean by "background processing"?

Comment: @roadmr That is what I was thinking as well. I couldn't find anything because it was so vague. I've asked the follow-up question. They do state we need the following, I wonder if this is what they are referring to? `Ensure opcache.save_comments is enabled. This is required for the plugin and product sync to work correctly.`

Comment: That looks on for me so that does not seem to be it: opcache.save_comments On On

Comment: That concept of background processing seems more of a Wordpress thing than an ubuntu one. Check https://wordpress.org/support/topic/your-site-does-not-support-background-processing/ for a bit more information but it unfortunately sounds off-topic for askubuntu.com.